# How to toast a message when you click on a disabled button?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have some disabled* buttons in an android app. How can I toast a message when you try to click on them ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about showin an enabled button as disabled ?

first you have to create two backgrounds disabled.xml and enabled.xml 
here is a website that helps you to do this
http://angrytools.com/android/button/
put them in the drawable/ folder

here is how to show button as disabled.

```
 button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.disabled);
```

to show it as enabled

```
 button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.enabled);
```

add boolean variable, that allows us to know the state of button

```
boolean disabled=true ;//if the button is disabled at first
```

and then when you enable button change the background and the value of the boolean variable

```
disabled=false;
button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.enabled);
```

and when you disable it

```
disabled=true;
button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.disabled);
```

how to use : add this in the button click listener

```
  if(disabled){
 Toast.makeText(this,"Button disabled",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else {
//do what you want when button is enabled
}
```

Comment: If I just show it as disabled and the user clicks on it, it will crash the application

Comment: let me test it with a real device , i will report in about 10 min

Comment: @JoshuaByer I will try it now, and get back to you

Comment: It says that it cannot find btn_default_normal

Comment: when using my custom background it enabled.xml and desabled.xml everything works fine .

Comment: What do you mean ? I can only find btn_defalt, btn_default_small etc., but not that one

Comment: yes i know that .. i used something like this .. but with my own drawable.. when i saw your question .. i googled how to get default android drawable for button and i 've got this result .. but it doesn't work .. so would you use custom backgrounds ?

Comment: I would if you tell me how and give me a link to download them :D

Comment: Actually I'll just paint them different colors. They don't have to look disabled anyway

Comment: yes you can choose any colors ... it s your problem now hahaha

Comment: Yeah, I used you disabled = true etc. Nice idea ^_^

Comment: yes use boolean a lot, it helps you to check states .. for example from other fucntion or class you can test if that button is disabled or not by just if(disabled){}else{} .. but you have to add static boolean disabled=false

Comment: why you want to create a disabled drawable? use this instead:
button.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default_normal_disabled);

Comment: @Leebeedev , i tried it few months ago, and if i'm still remembring it doesn't work with all  api versions...

Answer (score 0):

```
public String yabadabado="";


//OnCreate...

//Whatever action that disables button
button.setEnabled(false);
String yabadabado ="toastmessage";

//button.onClick....
if (yabadabado.equals("toastmessage"))
{toast your message}
else
{some other action}
```

Comment: if(input_string.equals("String"))
                        Toast.makeText(this, "String", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: But for some reason is telling me that it can't resolve method Toast.makeText

Comment: Your forgetting { } around toast like  if (){Toast.makeText(
           getApplicationContext(),"Sometoastmessage"
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}

Comment: No, the problem was the word "this". I replaced it with getApplicationContext() and not the error is gone. I ll test it and get back to you

Comment: I am talking about your idea with the strings, not about "MainActivity.this"

Answer (score -1):

My Solution involves creating two buttons.

A on Button that look good and normal and has the usual on click

A Off Button that looks like the on button but turned off and has the disabled onClick.

Make both of these dynamically using java in the activity, and than switch them within a container layout in the xml file at runtime.